# Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit no longer wakes up from sleep. (Black screen no monitor's signal)

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep, gpu, desktop-computer

Recently and all of a sudden my computer no longer wakes up from sleep. I used to have no such issue. Now when i wake up the computer the fans all working however the screen is just black like no signal but i can see the computer actually working and the Num Lock led is on but it's going off after about 2 seconds and whenever i click any keyboard key the Num lock on again and it will off again and so on. I tried to use CAPS Lock but it never light the led only Num Lock led will be on even with CAPS lock key? what is this problem?. I have changed nothing no hardware no software so what is this weird problem?

Also the reset button on case won't restart. It will stay black no signal screen. The only way to get the computer running again is to power off and on from the case button.

I am on 23 inch Samsung monitor with HDMI cable.

I read somewhere that the monitor could be not going out of sleep. Is this a sign that my GPU is failing to send wake up signal?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this issue, it is usually related to an update gone wrong, such as a display driver.

Personally I would try uninstalling and reinstalling your display driver through Device Manager.